# Validación de datos en formulario django al editar una instancia

Tags: django, django-forms

un saludo para todos.

Estoy creando un proyecto para agendar salones y elementos, los cuales solo podrán  estar disponibles en un horario en concreto.

Models.py

```
class Agenda(MarcadorTiempo):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    recurso_fisico = models.ForeignKey(RecursoFisico, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='recurso físico',
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    recurso_tecnologico = models.ManyToManyField(RecursoTecnologico, blank=True,
                                                 verbose_name='recurso tecnólogico', related_name='agenda_recurso',
                                                 help_text='Mantenga presionado "Control" o "Command" en un Mac, para '
                                                           'seleccionar más de una opción.')
    fecha_separacion = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Fecha de Separación', default=today())
    hora_separacion = models.TimeField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Hora de Separación')
    hora_devolucion = models.TimeField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Hora de Devolución')
```

Para cumplir con ello he creado la siguiente validación en el formulario.

Forms.py

```
class AgendaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agenda
        exclude = ['usuario']
        fields = ['fecha_separacion', 'hora_separacion', 'hora_devolucion', 'recurso_fisico', 'recurso_tecnologico']


    def clean_recurso_fisico(self):
        recurso_fisico = self.cleaned_data['recurso_fisico']
        fecha_separacion = self.cleaned_data['fecha_separacion']
        hora_separacion = self.cleaned_data['hora_separacion']
        hora_devolucion = self.cleaned_data['hora_devolucion']

        # Consulta de los elementos existentes en el mismo horario
        agenda_dia = Agenda.objects.filter(fecha_separacion=fecha_separacion)
        agenda_dia = agenda_dia.filter(Q(hora_separacion__range=(hora_separacion, hora_devolucion))
                                   | Q(hora_devolucion__range=(hora_separacion, hora_devolucion)))

        # Validación de disponibilidad
        for agenda in agenda_dia:
            if recurso_fisico == agenda.recurso_fisico:
                raise ValidationError('El {} ya fue agendado desde las {} hasta las {} por {}'.format(
                    recurso_fisico,
                    agenda.hora_separacion.strftime('%I:%M %p'),
                    agenda.hora_devolucion.strftime('%I:%M %p'),
                    agenda.usuario))

        return recurso_fisico


    def clean_recurso_tecnologico(self):
        recurso_tecnologico = self.cleaned_data['recurso_tecnologico']
        fecha_separacion = self.cleaned_data['fecha_separacion']
        hora_separacion = self.cleaned_data['hora_separacion']
        hora_devolucion = self.cleaned_data['hora_devolucion']

        # Consulta de los elementos existentes en el mismo horario
        agenda_dia = Agenda.objects.filter(fecha_separacion=fecha_separacion)
        agenda_dia = agenda_dia.filter(Q(hora_separacion__range=(hora_separacion, hora_devolucion))
                               | Q(hora_devolucion__range=(hora_separacion, hora_devolucion)))

        # Validación de disponibilidad
        for agenda in agenda_dia:
            for recurso in recurso_tecnologico:
                if recurso in agenda.recurso_tecnologico.all():
                    raise ValidationError('El {} ya fue agendado desde las {} hasta las {} por {}'.format(
                        recurso,
                        agenda.hora_separacion.strftime('%I:%M %p'),
                        agenda.hora_devolucion.strftime('%I:%M %p'),
                        agenda.usuario))

        return recurso_tecnologico
```

Así he logrado satisfacer el requerimiento, sin embargo cuando realizo la edición ejecuta la validación y me indica que los elementos ya existen, por lo cual no me permite guardar las modificaciones.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia que me puedan dar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo con ayuda de un amigo, quedo de las siguiente forma.

Agregamos una condición antes del recorrido `for` para excluir la instancia misma del `queryset`

```
# Validación realizada para excluir si es una instancia de si misma, y así queda habilitada para hacer edición
        if self.instance:
            agenda_dia = agenda_dia.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
```